# capturing in closures in Rust '21

Tags: rust, reference, closures, move

I just found out that the following code compiles in Rust 21 (used to not compile in 18)

```
fn get_func (i: &mut i32) -> impl Fn() -> i32 + '_ {
    || *i
}
```

Is there an implicit *move* of `i` involved ? If so, then why does the following code compile too?

```
fn get_func (i: &mut i32) -> impl Fn() -> i32 + '_ {
    let f = || *i;
    
    println!("{:?}", i);  // was expecting here to give borrow of moved variable error, `&mut` doesnt implement `Copy` trait
    
    f
}
```

Or instead is it implicitly moving (copying in this case) the value being pointed to? But then the following code should compile, which doesn't -- indicating it's moving the reference.

```
fn get_func (i: &mut i32) -> impl Fn() -> i32 {
    || *i
}
```

Comment: I _think_ that there is not an implicit move, but an implicit non-mutable reborrow, somewhat as if you wrote: `let f = { let ii = &*i; move || *ii };`. but I cannot find this new behavior documented anywhere... Maybe from [rfc/2229](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2229-capture-disjoint-fields.md): _References to structs would be made more precise by reborrowing fields..._

Comment: @rodrigo An implicit reborrow would explain it. Since the closure doesn't need a mutable but a shared reference, it also explains (along with an equivalent reborrow performed by `println!()`) how `println!()` can access the mut reference `i` while `f` refers to it. _Both_ the closure and `println!()` are reborrowing, and thus downgrading the mutable reference to two shared referenes. This is allowed, similar to how it's allowed to invoke `foo(&x.foo, &x.bar)` where `x` is `&mut FooBar`. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4b6fa5c524320e485be3fe4e709569bb

Comment: Looks more like syntactic sugar. Move can be omitted in the 2021 version. With `move || *i`, the example is compiled and behaves in the same way with versions 2018 and 2021.

Comment: Yes, it seems more to be implicitly *moving* `i`,  instead of *reborrow*.  In the second example, it is smart to "defer" the *move* to the end of the function.

Answer (score 2):

It's downgrading your `&mut` to a `&` and making as many copies as it needs to.

This is all a byproduct of the fact that `&mut` has all the permissions of `&`; in other words it's fine to downgrade from a mutable reference to a non-mutable reference, and it's fine to copy a non-mutable reference as many times as you want, so this is just doing both of those implicitly.

```rust
fn get_func (i: &mut i32) -> impl Fn() -> i32 + '_ {
    *i += 1; // fine, still mutable
    let f = || *i;
    println!("{}", *i); // fine, no mutability required
    *i += 1; // ERROR: cannot mutate *i while borrowed by f
    f
}
```

It's worth noting that if you actually do try to capture it as mutable, this happens.

```rust
fn get_func (i: &mut i32) -> impl FnMut() -> i32 + '_ {
    println!("{}", *i); // Fine
    *i += 1; // Fine
    let f = || {*i += 1; *i};
    println!("{}", *i); // ERROR: cannot borrow *i as immutable
    f
}
```

Also the lifetime doesn't refer to the return of the closure, but the closure itself. Because no memory is moved, the closure is only valid so long as the memory at `i`'s address remains valid. That's why removing the lifetime makes the code not compile.

In any case, all you really have to remember is the classic: "one mutable reference OR multiple immutable references, not both".